# MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage and ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, asp.net-mvc-4

Just trying to get work mvc4 with mvccontrib
I set base page in web.config (the same way i did in my mvc3 projects)

```
<pages pageBaseType="MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage">
```

But in run time i get an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0305: Using the generic type 'MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Source Error:



Line 32:     
Line 33:     
Line 34:     public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage {
Line 35:         
Line 36: #line hidden


Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\17698293\b6166ab6\App_Web_index.cshtml.a8d08dba.e7moq-gi.0.cs    Line: 34
```

May be some one may help with that? Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

Looks like the problem is:

If i set custom base class `<pages pageBaseType="MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage">` and if view does not have any custom model on it in such case i am getting that error. So in such case i just need to set model in the view to @model dynamic and it would work and than failed again, so i just change basePageType to its default and use `MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage<dynamic> and MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage<MyModel>` until it will be fixed in the next `MvcContrib/MVC 4` versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage` does not exist, there is only `MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage<T>`. If you don't have a model class, you could do `MvcContrib.FluentHtml.ModelWebViewPage<dynamic>`.

All that said, I have no idea of MVC Contrib will work with MVC4, typically one needs to at least recompile things against the new MVC version . . . .